# Finding the value for $x$ for which the series converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, geometric-progressions

I am unable to follow one if the steps described in this question. My question is, can someone describe the part I do not understand?

The full question and solution is below :

Find the value for $x$ for which the series $U=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)x^n$ converges.

$$(2n-1)(x^n)$$

Using the ratio test:

$$ \begin{align}
R&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2(n+1)-1)|x|^{n+1}}{(2n-1)|x|^n} \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} |x|\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} |x|\frac{2+1/n}{2-1/n} \\
&\implies |x|<1
\end{align} $$

I understand that from the second line to the third line the fraction is divided by $n$ on both numerator and denominator.

However I do not follow the transition from the first line to the second, as the $-1$ term in the numerator seems to just disappear.

I would very much appreciate if someone could clarify the areas where I am unsure and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're applying the ratio test to determine when the series converges. There are a couple of typos in your formulas and your typesetting. Here's how the reasoning should look: Write $u_n=(2n-1)x^n$. Then

$$
{u_{n+1}\over u_n} = {(2(n+1)-1 ) x^{n+1}\over (2n-1)x^n} = x\cdot {2n+1\over 2n-1} = x\cdot {2+\frac1n\over 2-\frac 1n},
$$
so 
$$\lim _{n\to\infty} \left|{u_{n+1}\over u_n}\right|=|x|.
$$
(The transition from $(2(n+1)-1 ) $ to $2n+1$ is algebra.)

Comment: Thankyou for you response, please can you describe the algebra used for this transition ? this is the exact part I do not understand

Comment: Distribute the $2$ across the $(n+1)$, like this: $2(n+1)-1 = 2n +2-1 = 2n +1$. The answer is $2n+1$ (*not* $2(n+1)$ as you've written it).

Comment: Thank you ! its so obvious now that you have pointed it out, hopefully I wont make that mistake again !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the root test, too. 
Indeed the sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)x^n$$ converges for $|x|<1$ because the $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}  \left ((2n-1)x^n\right )^{\frac{1}{n}}=|x|$$